# Rails 3.1 undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass, making twitter style app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods, undefined, null

I have an and users can login and view their own profile with a form to type in their status. What the user typed can only be seen by let say "his friends" right now, haven't worked on that but "his friends" can't see it. for example I run the up and without signing in I got to a user's profile, without me signing in makes the app show the status the user typed and that's when I get the error: 
    undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass

here is my users controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@microsposts = @user.microsposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end

 def create

    @microspost = current_user.microsposts.build(params[:microspost])

     if @microspost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to current_user
    else
       render 'home/index'
    end
  end


end
```

_microspost.html.erb:

```
  <%= microspost.content %>
```

_microspost_form.html.erb:

```
        <%= form_for @microspost do |f| %>
             <!--<render 'error_messages', :object => f.object %>-->
       <div class="field">
       <%= f.text_area :content %>
          </div>
      <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
```

I'm stuck on this one I'm so frustrated, I've been working on an app daily from non til 4am, now I gotta stop 45mins early because I just can't go on debugging this, it's been 2 hours.

I appreciate the help guy and gals....

and here is part of show.html:

```
    <% unless @user.microsposts.empty? %>
        <table class="microposts" summary= "User microposts">
      <%= render 'microspost' %>
      </table>
        <!--will_paginate @microsposts %>-->

        <% end %>

          <td class="sidebar round">
            <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @user.username %><br />
             <strong>URL:</strong> <%= link_to user_path(@user), @user %><br />
      <strong>Microposts:</strong><%= @user.microsposts.count %>
     </td>
     <% if signed_in? %>
        <table class = "front" summary="For signed in users">
  <tr>
    <td class="main">
        <h1 class="micropost">What you doin?</h1>
        <%= render 'microspost_form' %>
        </td>
        <td class ="sidebar round">
            <%= render 'user_info' %>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <% else %>
            <h1>testing test</h1>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `<%= render 'microspost' %>` with

- `<%= @user.microsposts %>` if `@user.microsposts` is an objet of class `Micropost`
- `<%= render :partial => 'microspost', :object =>  @user.microsposts %>` otherwise

Comment: ok i did that, now I get undefined method `model_name' 'for NilClass:Class' in the form_for @microspost do

Comment: @user1191343 it looks like it's the same problem with `<%= render 'microspost_form' %>`: here some help to use partials http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Got it! needed to add  @microspost = Microspost.new to my user controller, Thanks so much, your answer helped me look at things differently